# Read a text file using Javascript next() goes into an infinite loop

Tags: javascript

In my displayList() the The next() option should stop once it reaches the last record from the Movies list which is read from the films.txt file. Trying to display the list of items in an array. The next() method runs to be an infinite loop. Does anyone have a better suggestion.
Thank you

```
function List() {
    this.listSize = 0;
    this.pos = 0;
    this.dataStore = [];
    this.length = length;
    this.toString = toString;
    this.append = append;
    this.front = front;
    this.currPos = currPos;
    this.next = next;
    this.getElement = getElement;
}

function append(element){
    this.dataStore[this.listSize++] = element;
 }

 function length(){
    return this.listSize;
 }
 
 function toString(){
    return this.dataStore;
 }
 function front(){
    this.pos = 0;
 }
 function next(){
    if(this.pos < this.listSize - 1){
        ++this.pos;
    }
 }
 
 function currPos(){
    return this.pos;
 }

 function next(){
    if(this.pos < this.listSize - 1){
        ++this.pos;
    }
 }
  
 function getElement(){
    return this.dataStore[this.pos];
 }

function createArr(file) {
    const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
    const arr = readFileSync(file).toString().replace(/\r\n/g,'\n').split('\n');
    for(let i =0; i< arr.length; ++i){
       arr[i] =arr[i].trim();
    }
    return arr;
 }

 function displayList(list){
    for(list.front(); list.currPos() < list.length(); list.next()){        
            console.log(list.getElement());    
    }
    
}

let movies = createArr("films.txt");
let movieList = new List();
for(let i= 0 ; i < movies.length; ++i )
{
    movieList.append(movies[i]);
}
console.log("Available movies: \n");
displayList(movieList);
```

Data from films.txt Is below

- The Shawshank Redemption
- The God Father
- Pulp Fiction
- The Good, the bad and the Ugly
- 12 Angry Men

Output Printed on Console.log

- The Shawshank Redemption
- The God Father
- Pulp Fiction
- The Good, the bad and the Ugly
- 12 Angry Men
- 12 Angry Men
- 12 Angry Men
- 12 Angry Men

Comment: What's the point of the `List` class? Why not just use an ordinary array instead of wrapping it like this?

Comment: Typo: `NodeList.currPos()` should be `list.currPos()`.

Comment: What output are you getting? Why do you think the problem is with `fs.readFileSync()`? Have you tried doing `console.log(arr)` to see what was read from the file?

Comment: `if(this.pos < this.listSize - 1)` doesn’t need to deduct 1. As it is, `currPos()` will never equal `length()`